# LWC Community recordId undefined

Tags: lightning-community, lightning-web-components

I am very new to Salesforce and I am stuck using LWC with communities.
The problem is simple:
I generated my record list and when I click on the record I would like to access the selected record information on a detail page.
It works well when I hardcode the recordId but when using the @api recordId, the object I get is empty and recordId is undefined.
I am trying to display it on a custom Object page.

When trying to do the same in Salesforce itself, it works as I can reference the object in the meta XML.

Here is my code:
JS

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord, getFieldValue } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import MEETING_NAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Meeting__c.Name';

export default class ComMeetingHeader extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;

  @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: [MEETING_NAME_FIELD] })
  record;

  get meetingData() {
    return getFieldValue(this.record.data, MEETING_NAME_FIELD);
  }
}
```

HTML (object record seems to exist as it goes inside the if statement)

```
<template>
  <h1>{meetingData}</h1>
  <lightning-card title="Wire Function" icon-name="standard:contact">
      <template if:true={record}>
          <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
            <h1>Inside record</h1>
          </div>
      </template>
      <template if:true={error}>
          <h1>Inside error</h1>
          <div>{error}></div>
      </template>
  </lightning-card>
</template>
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" fqn="comMeetingHeader">
  <apiVersion>45.0</apiVersion>
  <isExposed>true</isExposed>
  <targets>
    <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
    <target>lightningCommunity__Page</target>
    <target>lightningCommunity__Default</target>
  </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add `<target>lightning__RecordPage</target>` to the XML and try

Comment: I tried your meta, and was able to save it and deploy in communities. It might be, it does not allow you to add that property to a component which is already used in active community. Can you remove your component from community builder and then save it?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal I did remove it saved and put it back but still no data displayed

Comment: @PranayJaiswal it is a custom object page where I put the component

Comment: @PranayJaiswal after removing it and uploading the config with only the lightning__RecordPage I can upload it (see updated post description) but I am still not able to retrieve the data.

Comment: @PranayJaiswal It works the information are displayed but I get the error:
This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. First, would you give us some details? (We're reporting this as error ID: 878968665)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90772/discussion-between-mehdikit-and-pranay-jaiswal).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From docs, you have to add `<target>lightning__RecordPage</target>` in the lwc component meta, for it to accept recordId from the detail [page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.migrate_interfaces).

```
<targets>
    <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
</targets>
```

> ```
> Indicates that the component takes a record Id as an attribute.
> ```

**EDIT**: Apparently this works in App builder, but in communities, things are a bit funny.

You have to explicitly expose the `recordId`using `<targetConfigs>`

```
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightningCommunity__Default">
            <property name="recordId" type="String" ></property>
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
```

Then in community builder provide the recordId as `{!recordId}`

Comment: I cannot use lightning_RecordPage in a community. When I do so I got the error:

Comment: You can't remove the lightningCommunity__Page from targets. You can't remove the lightningCommunity__Default from targets. This component is found in 2 Development Instance(s) and 1 Published Instance(s). Use the following component paths to locate the component: 
[Development] Full custom community > Record Detail (Widget) > header (Panel) > comMeetingHeader (Aura)
[Development] Full custom community > Meeting Detail (Widget) > header (Panel) > comMeetingHeader (Aura)
[Published] Full custom community > Meeting Detail (Widget) > header (Panel) > comMeetingHeader (Aura)

Comment: I did it already under XML

Comment: Here you go. I put the lightning__RecordPage together with the community tags otherwise I have the error I showed you.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the object record exists as it enters the if statement.

Comment: Thanks the new edit is the right answer !

Comment: @user3209853 How do I do that? I think I am too new and don't have the superpower to do such an action yet

Comment: Interestingly, while this works for `recordId` it doesn't for `objectApiName`, even when I tried using `{!sObjectName}` or `{!v.sObjectName}` as per https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:hasSObjectName/documentation

Comment: Faced the same issue. In my case, @api recordId was working without the target config in a sandbox. But in prod it didn’t work and required the target config.

Answer (score 2):

you might just be missing {!recordId} in the dialogue box when you add a component to community builder. For me that was the case
[image: as shown in the picture]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but for me '$recordId' did not work in wired getrecord function.
I was getting recordid data in renderedcallback() and in connectedcallack() i was getting it as undefined.
To resolve this, I wrote one apex method to fetch data related to record and called that apex method from renderedcallback()
Let me know if this helped to you.

Comment: It works.. just tried today