# Get RecordId in LWC From Community Page

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-community

I'm trying to make a component in my community be able to pull in the record Id.

I followed the information in this question: [LWC Community recordId undefined](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/253006/lwc-community-recordid-undefined)

And this documentation: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.use_config_for_community_builder

My config file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>45.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <masterLabel>ContractorSearch</masterLabel>
    <description>Searches for contractors for a given set of criteria</description>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Page</target>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Default</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordPage">
            <objects>
                <object>Requisition__c</object>
            </objects>
        </targetConfig>
        <targetConfig targets="lightningCommunity__Default">
            <property name="recordId" default="{!recordId}" type="String" 
                label="Record ID" description="Should not be changed from default value."/>
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Solution provided seems not working for me. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/413801/record-id-is-not-populating-to-lwc-in-record-page-in-community-experience-cloud

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Apparently Salesforce is not clever enough to understand when you put in `{!recordId}` as a default value.

Removing the default value and setting the property in the community fixed the issue.

```
<property name="recordId" type="String" 
    label="Record ID" description="The value should be {!recordId}."/>
```

### Update:

For people stumbling across this answer in the future, [here is the full code](https://github.com/gnerb/Salesforce-Samples/tree/master/ContractorSearch) of the component I made that is 100% functional.

Remember to set the variable in the component properties within your community:

[image]

JS:

```
import STATE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Requisition__c.State__c';
//... for all fields

const requisitionFields = [
    STATE_FIELD, //... For all fields
];

@api recordId;
@track requisition;

@wire(getRecord, {recordId:'$recordId', fields:requisitionFields})
    getRequisition({error, data}) { 
        if(data) {
            this.requisition = data;
        }
    }
}
```

And the target configuration looks like this:

```xml
<targetConfig targets="lightningCommunity__Default">
      <property name="recordId" type="String" label="Record ID" description="Should be set to {!recordId}"/>
</targetConfig>
```

### Update 2

[A similar question was posted here.](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/283267/lwc-getting-recordid-from-community-page/283382#283382) I have added another answer with copy/pasta code. The information is the same as what can be found in this answer and in the component I provided on github above; however, it is worded differently. If you are having issues with the answer above you can review the answer on the other question as well.

Comment: How did you access the recordId in the Js file?  console.log(recordId); doesn't return anything.

Comment: I would recommend asking another question where you can provide samples of your code and more information. I will keep an eye out and try to help you when I see it.

Comment: @cartman You should be able to access by setting `@api recordId` at the top of the class and `this.recordId` in the classes' methods but that doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: @gNerb I have done as you said but its not working for me

Comment: Awesome, thanks. It was totally not something I would have guessed off hand. You saved me like an hour or two. It worked for me - just remove the default setting from the meta.xml file, and manually entered the record id in the component on the community page in builder.

Comment: Note that setting the target property default to `{!recordId}` was omitted from this answer for some reason. I believe it did not work at the time, but certainly works for us, since probably mid to late 2020, even in a digital experience.