# How to add Dynamic Picklists to your LWC Design File for FlowScreen?

Tags: lightning-web-components, picklist, dynamic, flowscreen

What is the best way to add dynamic values as datasource to FlowScreen components? Is there a way? Assuming that it's not supported, what would be the best alternative to keep the code consistent.

I need to offer a limited number of options when adding an LWC component to Flows or Record pages in order to configure it properly.
[Dynamic picklist](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder_dynamic_picklists.htm) do address that requirement and it does work well for *lightning__RecordPage*, however it did not work when I added to *lightning__FlowScreen*. The code push works fine, but it didn't render, so field and options are not available.

The LightningComponentBundle datasource property is defined as follows.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
        <targets>
            <target>lightning__FlowScreen</target>
            <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        </targets>
        <targetConfigs>
            <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordPage">
                <property type="String" name="stage" label="Stage" datasource="apex://StagePicklist" description="Select the stage that should be used to load the correct template."/>
            </targetConfig>
            <targetConfig targets="lightning__FlowScreen">
                <property role="inputOnly" type="String" name="recordId" label="Record Id" description="Record Id of the main entity" />
                <property role="inputOnly" type="String" name="stage" label="Stage" datasource="apex://StagePicklist" description="Select the stage that should be used to load the correct template."/>
            </targetConfig>
        </targetConfigs>
        <apiVersion>51.0</apiVersion>
        <isExposed>true</isExposed>
        <masterLabel></masterLabel>
    </LightningComponentBundle>
```

Note: As a workaround I'm planning to create a String input field which accepts any value and then apply extra validations.

Comment: You should definetely take a look at custom property editors : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_flow_custom_property_editor_lwc_example

Comment: Thanks @MartinLezer for pointing that out! That's great content!

Comment: You're welcome ! You have really good examples in this free library provided by unofficialsf : https://github.com/alexed1/LightningFlowComponents/tree/master/flow_screen_components/FlowScreenComponentsBasePack
Take a look at the fsc_quickChoiceCpe lwc component.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get RecordId in LWC From Community Page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/261178/get-recordid-in-lwc-from-community-page)

Answer (score 1):

We need to create a new object and embed it as part of the target config.
Same example:

```
<targetConfig targets="lightning__FlowScreen" configurationEditor="c-stage-editor">
    <property role="inputOnly" type="String" name="recordId" label="Record Id" description="Record Id of the main entity" />
    <property role="inputOnly" type="String" name="stage" label="Stage" description="Select the stage that should be used to load the correct template."/>
</targetConfig>
```

A custom property editor uses JavaScript functions to communicate with Flow Builder, so it's possible to exchange values between flows and your component.

As pointed by @MartinLezer, there are a good documentation about it:

- [LWC - Use Flow Custom Property Editor Interface](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_flow_custom_property_editor_interface)
- [Flow screen components - Components Base Pack](https://github.com/alexed1/LightningFlowComponents/tree/master/flow_screen_components/FlowScreenComponentsBasePack)