# How to get recordid in community page using LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, record

**mymodal.html**

```
<template>
  <lightning-modal-header label="My Modal Heading"></lightning-modal-header>
    <lightning-modal-body> Content: {recordId} 
      console.log(recordId)

      <lightning-record-edit-form
        record-id={content}
        object-api-name="Account">

        <div class="slds-box">
            <lightning-input-field field-name="Name"> </lightning-input-field> 
            <lightning-input-field field-name="Phone"> </lightning-input-field>              
        </div>
        <lightning-button class="slds-m-top_small" variant="brand" type="submit" name="update" label="Update">
        </lightning-button>
    </lightning-record-edit-form>
    </lightning-modal-body>
    <lightning-modal-footer>
        <lightning-button label="OK" onclick={handleOkay}></lightning-button>
    </lightning-modal-footer>
</template>
```

**myModel.js**

```
import { api } from 'lwc';
import LightningModal from 'lightning/modal';

export default class MyModal extends LightningModal {
    @api content;
    @api recordId;
    @api content2;

    handleOkay() {
        this.close('okay');
    }
}
```

**myPage.html**

```
<template>
    <lightning-button
        onclick={handleClick}
        aria-haspopup="modal"
        label="Open My Modal">
    </lightning-button> 
    <p>Result: {result}</p>
</template>
```

**mypage.js**

```
import { LightningElement, api } from "lwc";
import NAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.Name';
import MyModal from "c/myModal";

export default class MyPage extends LightningElement {
    nameField = NAME_FIELD;
   

    // Flexipage provides recordId and objectApiName
    @api recordId;
    
    @api objectApiName;
    async handleClick() {
        console.log(this.recordId+ ' recordId');
        // console.log(this.nameField+ ' nameField');
        // console.log(this.currentPageReference.state.recId);
        const result = await MyModal.open({
            size: 'large',
            description: 'Accessible description of modal\'s purpose',
            content: this.recordId,

          //  content2: this.recordId,

           
        });
        // if modal closed with X button, promise returns result = 'undefined'
        // if modal closed with OK button, promise returns result = 'okay'
        console.log(result);
    }
}
```

**My output**

[image: my output is like below picture but i need same result in community page whenever i click on and record.My error is :- recordid is not able to fetch in community]

Comment: The important thing you didn't include was the LWC's meta XML. This is where you list the target properties and it is here that, for community page use, you must list the `recordId` property with a default value of `{!recordId}`. See the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_record_context).

Comment: You will have similar issues with `objectApiName`, as covered [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_object_context).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get RecordId in LWC From Community Page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/261178/get-recordid-in-lwc-from-community-page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close, you just need to update your XML file like this -

It'll work only if you add the component to the Record Detail page on the community.

```
    <targets>
            <target>lightningCommunity__Page</target>
            <target>lightningCommunity__Default</target>
        </targets>
        <targetConfigs>
            <targetConfig targets="lightningCommunity__Default">
                <property name="recordId" type="String" label="Record ID" description="Should be set to {!recordId}" default="{!recordId}"/>
<!-- this will create a property on the community page-->
            </targetConfig>
        </targetConfigs>
```

[image]