# Record Id is not populating to LWC in Record Page in Community (Experience Cloud)

Tags: lightning-web-components, community, experience-cloud

I have a problem capturing the record id from a record page in communities.

I followed [Get RecordId in LWC From Community Page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/261178/get-recordid-in-lwc-from-community-page) intructions but it's not working for me and i saw that is not working for more people.

As my LWC contains a lot of content i created a simple LWC that shows only the Record ID

ShowRecordId LWC

HTML

```html
    <template>
        <p>Record Id: {recordId}</p>
    </template>
```

JS

```js
    import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';
    
    export default class ShowRecordId extends LightningElement {
        @api recordId;
    }
```

META

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
        <apiVersion>58.0</apiVersion>
        <isExposed>true</isExposed>
        <masterLabel>Record Id</masterLabel>
        <targets>
            <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
            <target>lightningCommunity__Page</target>
            <target>lightningCommunity__Default</target>
        </targets>
        <targetConfigs>
            <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordPage">
                <property name="recordId" type="String" label="Record ID" description="Should be set to {!recordId}"/>            
            </targetConfig>
            <targetConfig targets="lightningCommunity__Default">
                <property name="recordId" type="String" label="Record ID" description="Should be set to {!recordId}"/>            
            </targetConfig>
        </targetConfigs>
    </LightningComponentBundle>
```

Result

I access to the page customer following the url

[image]

I added in the record page a standard record component to show that this is capturing the recordId from the context

[image]

Also I have seen that before publish I see an error that the record id is not being shown.

Here I just duplicated the ShowRecordId component in the Record Page

[image]

***Error: Experience Builder can't display this component because its record ID isn't well formed. In the Propery Editor,enter a well-formed ID in the Record Id field --- for example {!recordId}.***

But in this case here I put {!recordId}

[image]

Comment: Set the default value for the target property to `{!recordId}` instead of requiring the admin to set it manually. Please [edit] your question to show how the digital experience page's URL is configured. It should be something like `/:recordId` which is then where the variable used in the expression gets its value - the actual URL reference to the ID gets put into the variable which is then passed to the component.

Comment: @PhilW the question OP referenced: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/261178/get-recordid-in-lwc-from-community-page Specifically exists because setting the default value in the component meta file did not work at the time of writing, has that been changed?

Comment: David, The question you mentioned has a link to a second question I answered: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/261178/get-recordid-in-lwc-from-community-page which covers how the page actually populates the {!recordId} variable making it available. Have you tried /customers/0017a00002ER64LAAT /juan-cuesta?recordId=0017a00002ER64LAAT

Comment: @gNerb all I can say is that it works for us.

Comment: @PhilW Might be worth adding an answer to the original question stating that it is now supported so when new people stumble on the question they don't spend time on a solution that is no longer necessary.

Comment: I added a comment...