# LWC not rendering correctly on Communities

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-community

LWC renders fine inside the Org, but just an empty lightning card on Communities.  Have set the targets up for communtiies, community profile has acccess tot he Apex, they're apex enabled, CSP Trust is enabled for the callout to AWS, FLS and object perms correct cos they can see the record "natively".  No errors in browser debug.

LWC just renders a list of RTF fields, nothing complex at all.

**Apex controller**

```
public without sharing class imageAttachmentController
{
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<SObject> getImages(Id recordId, String objectName)
    {
        System.debug(recordId + ' - ' + objectName);
        List<SObject> images = new List<SObject>();
        
        if(recordId != null && objectName != null)
        {
            String objectType = recordId.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName();
            if(objectType == 'WorkOrder')    //Work Order
            {
                String query = 'SELECT Image_RTF__c FROM ' + objectName + ' WHERE Work_Order__c = \'' + recordId + '\'';
                System.debug(query);
                images = Database.query(query);
            }
            else if(objectType == 'WorkOrderLineItem')   //Work Order Line Item
            {
                String query = 'SELECT Image_RTF__c FROM ' + objectName + ' WHERE Work_Order_Line_Item__c = \'' + recordId + '\'';
                System.debug(query);
                images = Database.query(query);
            }
        }
        return images;
    }
}
```

**JS controller**

```
import { LightningElement, wire, api, track } from 'lwc';
import getImages from '@salesforce/apex/imageAttachmentController.getImages';

export default class ImageAttachmentViewer extends LightningElement
{
    
    @api listType;
    @api recordId;

    listlabel;

    @wire(getImages, {recordId: '$recordId', objectName: '$listType'})
    images;

    connectedCallback()
    {
        console.log(this.listType);

        switch(this.listType)
        {
            case 'Work_Order_Attached_Image__c':
                this.listlabel = 'Work Order Images';
                break;
            case 'Work_Order_Item_Attached_Image__c':
                this.listlabel = 'Work Order Item Images';
                break;
            case 'Damage_Report_Attached_Image__c':
                this.listlabel = 'Damage Report Images';
                break;
            case 'Risk_Assessment_Attached_Image__c':
                this.listlabel = 'Risk Assessment Images';
                break;
            case 'Meter_Attached_Image__c':
                this.listlabel = 'Meter Images';
                break;
            case 'Meter_Reading_Attached_Image__c':
                this.listlabel = 'Meter Reading Images';
                break;
            case 'Work_Inspection_Form_Attached_Image__c':
                this.listlabel = 'Work Inspection Form Content Images';
                break;
            default:
                this.listlabel = 'Attached images';
        }
    }
}
```

**Markup**

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title={listlabel}>
        <ul class="slds-var-m-around_medium">
            <template for:each={images.data} for:item="image">
                    <li key={image.Id}>
                        <lightning-formatted-rich-text value={image.Image_RTF__c}></lightning-formatted-rich-text>
                    </li>
            </template>
        </ul>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

**Meta**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>49.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Page</target>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Default</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordPage">
            <property name="listType" type="String" datasource="apex://imageViewerDesignController" label="Related List Type"/>
        </targetConfig>
        <targetConfig targets="lightningCommunity__Default">
            <property name="listType" type="String" datasource="apex://imageViewerDesignController" label="Related List Type"/>
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

**Design Controller**

```
global class imageViewerDesignController extends VisualEditor.DynamicPickList
{
    global override VisualEditor.DataRow getDefaultValue()
    {
        VisualEditor.DataRow defaultValue = new VisualEditor.DataRow('Work Order', 'WorkOrder');
        return defaultValue;
    }

    global override VisualEditor.DynamicPickListRows getValues()
    {
        VisualEditor.DataRow workOrderValue = new VisualEditor.DataRow('Work Order', 'Work_Order_Attached_Image__c');
        VisualEditor.DataRow workOrderItemValue = new VisualEditor.DataRow('Work Order Line Item', 'Work_Order_Item_Attached_Image__c');
        VisualEditor.DataRow meterValue = new VisualEditor.DataRow('Meter', 'Meter_Attached_Image__c');
        VisualEditor.DataRow meterReadingValue = new VisualEditor.DataRow('Meter Reading', 'Meter_Reading_Attached_Image__c');
        VisualEditor.DataRow workInspectionFormContentValue = new VisualEditor.DataRow('Work Inspection Form Content', 'Work_Inspection_Form_Attached_Image__c');
        VisualEditor.DataRow damageReportValue = new VisualEditor.DataRow('Damage Report', 'Damage_Report_Attached_Image__c');
        VisualEditor.DataRow riskAssessmentValue = new VisualEditor.DataRow('Risk Assessment', 'Risk_Assessment_Atttached_Image__c');

        VisualEditor.DynamicPickListRows  picklistValues = new VisualEditor.DynamicPickListRows();
        picklistValues.addRow(workOrderValue);
        picklistValues.addRow(workOrderItemValue);
        picklistValues.addRow(meterValue);
        picklistValues.addRow(meterReadingValue);
        picklistValues.addRow(workInspectionFormContentValue);
        picklistValues.addRow(damageReportValue);
        picklistValues.addRow(riskAssessmentValue);
        return picklistValues;

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you at least seeing the console.log from connectedCallback? Are listType and recordId being set correctly the same way in the community builder than in the internal record page? Did you publish the community after adding the component? I've forgotten to do that more than once and wondered where my changes are 

Comment: Yes to all of those.  Admin at client is the one with Prod access, so watching via screenshare, but seems to be covered.  RecordId comes in automatically, doesn't it?  Even if it doesn't, I've annotated with api so it should pick it up, certainly does in a non-COmmunity recordpage view

Comment: Can.you share the lwc meta file (the one with targetConfigs, etc. I can't remember the exact name) My next approach would be changing the wired property to a method so I can put a debugger and inspect the response to see if there's an error there. (Or put a trace on the community user to see if the apex is actually being run)

Comment: Yes can we get your target configure?

Comment: Added - I know the targetconfigs can be combined into one now, but that shouldn't be the issue, right?

Comment: Meta looks good AFAIK the recordId gets pulled in automatically. Is there anything in images.error? Have you seen the apex log to see that both parameters are passed to the apex method correctly?

You have nerd-sniped me here lol

Comment: More debugging and log checking tonight. I've been recommended the Lightning Inspector to see what's going on.  99% sure it's not data permissions as the underlying record is visible in Community. The Console.lgo for the label I have in there works, so it's hitting the control at least.

Comment: @adriancg - only thing shown from the Apex logs is it hitting the Designer class (the one that allows properties to be set when designing the page), which seems an odd class to call at Runtime....

Comment: @RobCowell could it be that there is something in imageViewerDesignController that the community user doesn't have access to and it's throwing? Have you tried calling imageAttachmentController.getImages imperatively instead of using the wire service?

Sorry to dump the contents of my brain here but this looks like it's going to be an obscure issue to solve

Comment: Nah, it's just picklist rows, will add to the OP

Comment: Do they have access to the class itself?

Comment: Yup, access to controller class and designer class added. Still no joy

Comment: In the Connected Callback, I console.log recordId and it comes back undefined.

Comment: Solved!  You gave to explicitly declare the recordID property in communities, it's not automatic like it is inside the Org.  See https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/253011/1027

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting as an answer for anyone stumbling onto this thread with a similar issue

Communities seems to work a little differently (as at Dec 2020) with regard to RecordID.  It's not automatically provided, even if you specify it in your component with an @api tag.  You need to explicitly mark it as a property in your .js-meta.xml in the targetConfig secttion, like so `<property name="recordId" type="String" ></property>`

Additionally, when adding your component to a record page for communities in Experience Builder, you will need to set this property to the value `{!recordId}` as shown below

[image]